# How to Convert Colour Names into Hexadecimal values in Java

Tags: java, hex

I have a color name as `String ("RED")` and i needed to convert it into hexadecimal.How do i achieve this.

Could you even convert that using java ?

Since I used awt package,

```
Color getColor = Color.getColor(color);
String hexCode = "#" + Integer.toHexString(getColor.getRGB()).substring(2).toUpperCase();
```

**Note**: I don't want to use `java.awt.Color` package

Comment: What is reason to not using use java.awt.Color ?

Comment: @SudhirOjha It's an old one, I wanna try with other solution

Comment: @dwayneJohn, what do you mean the `java.awt.Color` is old? If so why it is [included](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Color.html) in Java 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use any other class, you can achieve this by simply using a lookup table, which is just a map.

```
String color = "RED";

Map<String, String> lookupTable = new TreeMap<>();
lookupTable.put("RED", "#ff0000");
System.out.println(lookupTable.get(color));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaFX [Color](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#web(java.lang.String)).

```
javafx.scene.paint.Color orange = javafx.scene.paint.Color.web("orange");
```

The rest you know.

Comment: In Java 11 it means an additional [dependency](https://openjfx.io/).

Comment: @Boris Indeed, it is **OpenJFX** now, independent of java SE. However HTML/CSS color names are something not for core Java. Unfortunately I do not know of a central module like the unifying Base64 class that substituted duplicate implementations. And CSS color names form a standard, for which I would use a solid library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the java.awt.Color :/,

If you don't want to use it then you need to add each color manually into an array then get the value from the array.

Or use some online API, 
Like http://www.thecolorapi.com

Comment: It's a bunch of color codes. So it may take time to add manually trying with other option

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use java.awt.Color class has suggested.
For example you can use this method to convert from name to Color:

```
public static Color stringToColor(final String value) {
    if (value == null) {
      return Color.black;
    }
    try {
      // get color by hex or octal value
      return Color.decode(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
      // if we can't decode lets try to get it by name
      try {
        // try to get a color by name using reflection
        final Field f = Color.class.getField(value);

        return (Color) f.get(null);
      } catch (Exception ce) {
        // if we can't get any color return black
        return Color.black;
      }
    }
  }
```

Once you have the Color you can get his Hexadecimal value like this:

```
String hex = "#"+Integer.toHexString(your_color.getRGB()).substring(2);
```

**If you don't want to use java.awt.Color (because it's old, as you said), you can try to use "javafx.scene.paint.Color" to accomplish the same behaiviour**